# I want to get all the images stored in an android device to display them into my React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to build a custom gallery using React Native for that I have to read all the images stored on an android device. So I want to know How can I read all image files stored on a device

Answer (score 0):

you need READ PERMISSION from android

`import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';`

Try below code after importing above line

```js
const requestExternalReadPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Read Storage Permission',
          message: 'App needs Read Storage Permission',
        },
      );
      // If READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      alert('Read permission err', err);
    }
    return false;
  };
  
    const openGallery = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      
       if (await requestExternalReadPermission()) {
            setIsPermitted(true);
          } else alert('READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied');
       }
  };
```